# How to Customize Figure Section Header for EndFloat?

Tags: endfloat

I've been using the endfloat package, and calling `\proecessdelayedfloats` at the end of every chapter. I have `fighead` enabled, so that at the end of every chapter I see **Figures** as the header followed by my figures.

Is there a way to redefine `\processdelayedfloats` so that I can have customized headers for the delayed figures (ie **Figures for Chapter 2**)?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nomarkers,nofiglist,fighead]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\begin{figure}
\caption{
  A delayed figure.
}
\end{figure}

\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shame this never received an answer. I think this implies that this is not possible...